# Delphi XE 2 Translation do not compile - missing PENDLG.dfm for TeeChart

Tags: delphi, translation, teechart

I was working the last days on the translation of my project but the DLL with the transated ressources had never been created. The compiler said:
"[Fehler] E1026 Datei nicht gefunden: 'vcl\PENDLG.dfm'"
should be in English:
"[Error] E1026 File not found: 'vcl\Pendlg.dfm'"

I have Delphi XE2 Professional installed and use the default TChart.
Parts of the project were converted from Delphi 7, and I think the TChart also.
Can anybody please help or provide the missing dfm file?

Thanks

Comment: Try this: http://www.google.com/m?q=PENDLG.dfm